# Change active menu on horizontal website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm making this horizontal website, and i would like to change the active menu according to actual page.

I could achieve to change active menu on click, but not on scrolling (page position).

This is my website: http://www.finecolor.com.br/bandainky

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some javascript.

add (and tweak) this:

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    switch (window.pageYOffset%window.innerWidth) {
        case 0:
            //in this case, the first item should be active
            //so add your class .menu-active to it 
            break;
        case 1:
            //in this case, the second item should be active
            //so add your class .menu-active to it 
            break;
        [...] //add as many cases as you want
        default:
            //whatever default behavior you want
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, based on the quick look i got of your website's code, it seems that you are using classes as ids. When you know that an element is going to be the only one to bear a certain class, it should be styled with an ID instead. All your `menuli` elements have `menu-banda`, `menu-agenda`... as classes. instead, make those IDs:

```
id="menu-agenda" class="menuli"
```